# How to make a SQLlite row without adding another identical row while running the code multiple times?

Tags: python, sqlite

This is the code I am using:

```
def setbase():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("gamebase.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (box TEXT, score INTEGER)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'scores' IF NOT EXISTS VALUES (box, score) ('a', 2)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'scores' (box, score) VALUES ('b', 0)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'scores' (box, score) VALUES ('c', 0)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'scores' (box, score) VALUES ('d', 0)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

When I run this code everything is fine but when i run it multiple times the row keeps on adding and adding.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: what does it occur provided you add `IF NOT EXISTS` also for the second,third and the fourth insert statements as in the first one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify what makes your rows unique. In order to avoid duplicates in subsequent executions it can then be checked if a row with the same identity already exists. For example if 'box' values are unique, you'd first select by box and only insert if it does not return a result.

Another way is a concept called upsert which is [supported by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).